# Where can I get tag data for MP3s?

Tags: music, mp3, id3, tag

I have a large number of MP3 music tracks without MP3 tags.  I would like to add the tag data.

I understand the mechanics of using the various GUI tag editors as well as how to use ID3V2, but my question is where do I get the tag *data* from?  Is there a convenient way of finding out, for example, what year a particular song was released in?

Comment: Look for software that supports online music databases like cddb or freedb such as https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/easytag/

Answer (score 2):

Look into [MusicBrainz Picard](https://picard.musicbrainz.org) - especially the audio fingerprinting part.

Short excerpt from the [documentation](https://picard.musicbrainz.org/quick-start/):

> use the **Scan** toolbar button to lookup files using their **AcoustID**, which is a unique finger-print associated with each recording.

Comment: This thread is so old I no longer care about it.  And Picard is useless.

Answer (score 2):

MusicBrainz Picard tags and provides the data all at once.
To install, open a terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and enter

```
sudo apt-get install picard
```